# Is it possible to set up aliases of words in Sphinx?

Tags: sphinx

Suppose you have a database of articles that reference authors and you want to be able to find results even when an alias is used. For example:

```
Stephen King
-> Richard Bachman
-> Gus Pillsbury
```

If someone searches Richard Bachman, I also want it to return Stephen King results (and perhaps vice versa). However, I also want to continue to find results that explicitly use the Bachman name.

I looked into wordforms (ref: http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-wordforms) and tried something like this:

```
richard bachman => stephen king
gus pillsbury => stephen king
```

However, this seems to completely replace either pen name with king and doesn't also continue to search for the original query.

Perhaps something like this doesn't exist, or perhaps I just don't know the right wording for it to find it, but so far, coming up empty.

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit tricky but could do

```
richard bachman => richard bachman stephen king
gus pillsbury => gus pillsbury stephen king
```

This way if search for just "bachman" then the document index still has the the word "bachman" in it.

May also want

```
stephen king => stephen king richard bachman gus pillsbury
```

so that searching for "bachman" will also  still find stephen king books too.

... it breaks down a bit on phrase seraches, eg seraching for

```
"some say stephen king is a great author"
```

that would still find documents that DO have that quote, as the document AND query will change to

```
"some say stephen king richard bachman gus pillsbury is a great author"
```

But a document that contained "some say gus pillsbury is a great author" would not match. BUt could perhaps just make sure the names are all in the same order in the destination tokens.

Comment: Can't thumbs up, but thank you. I think there's something else amiss in our config, but this set us on the right path.